# GNU make - conflicting commandline params - takes the first or last one?

Tags: gnu-make

If I have `make all -j -j1`, which parallel option will `make` take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just try it and see.  It would be a lot faster than asking a question on SO and waiting for an answer.

But the answer is, the last one takes precedence.